# How can I change scientific notation to decimal?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have an output list of very large numbers
list= [... 3.562242402063122*10^766,2.212822298688101*10^771,1.388658821363273*10^776,8.803352353764781*10^780,5.637439700644651*10^785,3.646490131351477*10^790]

I need to use this as an input to a different code and I have noticed that the code is numerically more stable when input is in decimals instead of exponents. So I wanted to know how can I convert the above list in decimal notation.

Comment: Is `3.56224240206312210^766` from the real world?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!